# Iterate over tensor as an array Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, tensorflow

I am trying to save the predicted images on my CNN network which I wrote with Tensorflow. In my code `y_pred_cls` contain my predicted labels and the `y_pred_cls` is a tensor of dimensions 1 x batch size. Now, I want to iterate over y_pred_cls as an array and make a file name including pred class, true class, and some index number, then find out images relate to predicted labels and use `imsave` to save as image.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
train_writer.add_graph(sess.graph)



print("{} Start training...".format(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
print("{} Open Tensorboard at --logdir {}".format(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), tensorboard_dir))

for epoch in range(FLAGS.num_epochs):
    print("{} Epoch number: {}".format(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), epoch + 1))
    step = 1

    # Start training
    while step < train_batches_per_epoch:
        batch_xs, batch_ys = train_preprocessor.next_batch(FLAGS.batch_size)
        opt, train_acc = sess.run([optimizer, accuracy], feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_true: batch_ys})

        # Logging
        if step % FLAGS.log_step == 0:
            s = sess.run(sum, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_true: batch_ys})
            train_writer.add_summary(s, epoch * train_batches_per_epoch + step)

        step += 1

    # Epoch completed, start validation
    print("{} Start validation".format(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
    val_acc = 0.
    val_count = 0
    cm_running_total = None

    for _ in range(val_batches_per_epoch):
        batch_tx, batch_ty = val_preprocessor.next_batch(FLAGS.batch_size)
        acc, loss , conf_m= sess.run([accuracy, cost, tf.confusion_matrix(y_true_cls, y_pred_cls, FLAGS.num_classes)],
                                      feed_dict={x: batch_tx, y_true: batch_ty})



        if cm_running_total is None:
            cm_running_total = conf_m
        else:
            cm_running_total += conf_m


        val_acc += acc
        val_count += 1

    val_acc /= val_count

    s = tf.Summary(value=[
        tf.Summary.Value(tag="validation_accuracy", simple_value=val_acc),
        tf.Summary.Value(tag="validation_loss", simple_value=loss)
    ])

    val_writer.add_summary(s, epoch + 1)
    print("{} -- Training Accuracy = {:.4%} -- Validation Accuracy = {:.4%} -- Validation Loss = {:.4f}".format(
        datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), train_acc, val_acc, loss))

    # Reset the dataset pointers
    val_preprocessor.reset_pointer()
    train_preprocessor.reset_pointer()

    print("{} Saving checkpoint of model...".format(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))

    # save checkpoint of the model
    checkpoint_path = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, 'model_epoch.ckpt' + str(epoch+1))
    save_path = saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path)
    print("{} Model checkpoint saved at {}".format(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), checkpoint_path))
```

batch_tx, batch_ty is my RGB data and labels respectively.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should create `tf.confusion_matrix(y_true_cls, y_pred_cls, FLAGS.num_classes)` only once before the outer loop, otherwise you will be creating multiple instances of the same operation in the graph.

Comment: Hey @jdehesa, Where should I exactly create `tf.confusion_matrix()` ? because if I create confusion matrix after the loop, I will just get the confusion matrix for each batch and for having confusion matrix I have to feed `x: batch_tx, y_true: batch_ty` otherwise I will get an error.

Comment: You should be able to do something like `conf_mat = tf.confusion_matrix(y_true_cls, y_pred_cls, FLAGS.num_classes)` on graph construction time (before any of the training loops), right after you have defined both `y_true_cls` and `y_pred_cls`. Then within the loop just do `acc, loss , conf_m= sess.run([accuracy, cost, conf_mat], feed_dict={x: batch_tx, y_true: batch_ty})` (unless I'm not understanding something...)

Comment: I did as you said add `conf_mat = tf.confusion_matrix(y_true_cls, y_pred_cls, FLAGS.num_classes)` before starting my `tf.Session()` and within the loop I did `acc, loss , conf_m= sess.run([accuracy, cost, conf_mat], feed_dict={x: batch_tx, y_true: batch_ty})` but still getting confusion matrix for a batch and I need to sum up the confusion matrix of all batchs to get a full confusion matrix which results is exaclty same as I did before.

Comment: Ahh ok that's what you meant, right, yes you still have to do that, what I was saying is just that if you keep calling `tf.confusion_matrix` within the loop you are creating many copies of the same TensorFlow op that stay in you graph, so it's better to create just once and reuse it. But yes your code is correct otherwise.

Comment: You are right. Actually, I didn't know that which I am creating many copies of the same TF op. Nice point, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract data from a tensor into a python-variable use

`label = sess.run(y_pred_cls)`

This will give you an array for a one-hot-vector label or an int variable for a scalar label.

To save arrays to images you can use the PIL-library

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.fromarray(data, 'RGB')
img.save('name.png')
```

The rest should be straight forward,

1. extract data from your batch_tx, batch_ty and y_pred_cls tensors
2. iterate over each triplet
3. create an RGB image out of current `x`
4. create a string of the form `name = str(y)+'_'+str(y_hat)`
5. save your image

If you have trouble applying these steps I can help you out further

Comment: Probably you'd need `label = sess.run(y_pred_cls, feed_dict={x: batch_tx})`, or just extend the existing call to `.run` to evaluate `y_pred_cls` too...

Comment: Yeah thats true if you do it from within the current flow of your program

Comment: Hey @JonathanR , Can you help me more. I will get the predicted labels as you said with this line of code `label = sess.run(y_pred_cls, feed_dict={x: batch_tx})` and the label output is array([0, 3, 3, ...,0, 2, 1]) with lenght of 128 (my batch_size is 128), What is the next setp? How am I going to find images related to predicted labels?

Comment: Your output-array (if implemented correctly) will correspond to your input-array, meaning `y_pred_cls[0]` will be the label for `batch_tx[0]`. So simply do a for loop

Comment: @JonathanR `batch_tx[0]` is my first test image which is an array with shape (96, 96, 3). I have tried to convert the array to the image but I am getting something weird. For converting the array to image I did as follow: `img = Image.fromarray(data1, 'RGB')`; `img.show()` Am I doing wrong?

Comment: data1 is my first test image `batch_tx[0]`

Comment: Actually it looks like your input data1 is wrong then. Maybe try `Image.fromarray(data1).convert("RGB")` and see if there is a difference. E: note that all values in your image should be uint8, not floats etc

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have used CV2 library `img = cv2.resize(batch_tx[i], (FLAGS.img_size, FLAGS.img_size))`instead of PIL and got images same as original one and the rest as you said. Cheers